# Power BI Desktop / Partial load

Tags: powerbi

I want to integrate a new Data Source to my Power BI report and load all data from there. So far so good.

The only problem is, that this new Source has a data load limit of 250 rows per load. 
My Question is now: Is it possible to load data in a loop in Power BI Desktop?

Comment: What is your source?  The limitation sounds like a problem with your source rather than a Power BI issue.

Comment: It's Zendesk.
It's configured like that and I thought that I can bypass it with a loop.

Comment: I think you'll need to address this in the source system.  Maybe, but i dont think this type of issue can be resolved in Power BI.  Power Bi is presentation layer.